# what is the intensity of photon before and after striking the glass prism?

Tags: radiation, dispersion, glass

during dispersion we all know that white light enters in to the prism and disperses into the visible radiation, my question is whether a glass prism can eliminate other wavelengths and allow only visible radiation if so the energy of the photon passing the prism decreases or not?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal prism does not do this, a device which passes some frequencies and allows others to pass is called a filter.
Some prisms can also be filters.

Filters tend to selectively pass some photons and not others, so if there are a lot going through the overall intensity will reduce.

Certain glasses can allow visible but filter parts of non-visible spectrum out, yes.

If you have a prism, you can mask off different physical locations and achieve filtering that way. You can know where the visible light will emerge from the prism.

(Intensity is not a property of individual photons, which have a certain amount of energy. This energy is dependent on frequency/colour. Thus a prism sorts photons out into different energies. )